Ubuntu 24.04 screen glitches on gnome apps after install

Hello,
Just installed ubuntu 24.04.
I have some glitches on my screen. Text items are missing and apperead when mouse hover. This problem affect gnome settings, files etc.
I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 710 and Nvidia 470 driver installed.
I'm using debian 12 with same nvidia driver without any problem in same machine.
Can anyone give me help for this problem ?
Thanks

Same problem for me, works fine in maximized window

I have also tried driver 470 on 24.04 and I noticed the same issue with an RTX 3070. I don’t seem to have this issue with driver 535 but I guess it is not compatible with your gpu.

Ok, I have the issue with 535 as well now

Problem fixed. Thanks to @george-panov's comment I found the solution in @drnez2008's comment in Reddit:
Just update /etc/environment
GSK_RENDERER=gl

and restart.

Thank you ertankayalar. you just saved me. I had same problem on fresh installation of noble.

I've got exactly the same trouble after upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04 today. I had to try many suggested solutions to fix the problem, but nothing helped.
After that just reinstalled the nvidia drivers (535) and the problem has gone.
Here is a link on how to reinstall the drivers:
https://www.liberiangeek.net/2024/04/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-24-04/

After installed 535 driver display not showing only black screen

Reinstallation is not solved the problem.

Check this out  https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/1bnjx22/gnome_apps_do_not_show_text_unless_fullscreen/
the same problem but different solution

Above answer/solution by @george-panov / ertankayala,
Fixed the issue for me, Thanks
Just update (file in text editor) /etc/environment
(and add below line in a new line, followed by enter or blank new line)
GSK_RENDERER=gl
(save) and restart.

duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1511888/
