Keepass2 popup dialog box options blank
Been away being an npc on windows for years, decided to come back to linux but I'm very rusty. Trying to get keepass2 up and running properly and I'm running into an issue where the dialog boxes pop up and the "are you sure you want to delete this entry" message is visible but the clickable option boxes for "ok" etc. or "cancel" are blank. Would kind of like to know what I'm clicking. Tried to uninstall and reinstall keepass, no change. Anyone have an idea on how to get this sorted out?
Edit: sorry about that
Running 24.04 lts, new install. Keepass2 version 2.56
Selection boxes ok
Selection boxes blank
Starting keepass2 from terminal yielded following error message

Gtk-Message: 14:09:06.192: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

installed additional packages

sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module

Still no change. Starting from terminal now yields no messages.

Try including screenshots or logfiles if you have them.

Are you using an nVidia card? It might or might not be the same issue as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511575/ubuntu-24-04-screen-glitches-on-gnome-apps-after-install , can you try the top answer?

No nVidia card.  Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)

Others have had problems with keepass2 on Ubuntu 24.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512627/impatient-user-upgraded-from-23-10-to-24-04-desktop-on-laptop-there-are-several

KeePassXC is another option to try.

Ya I decided to give keepassxc a try. Not a bad option and may stick with it if I can get it's issues sorted. I'm getting a clipboard auto clear issue when the window isn't in focus for one, and I used to keep my keepass file on onedrive to access a synchronized file between the pc and my phone.

I've solved the onedrive being unmounted on resume/login issue but there's something going on with keepassxc saving to onedrive when I make a change in my database. I'm playing with it and found saving .txt files to onedrive creates the file and saves the name but doesn't save any content. Read about it happening with .csv files as well. I'm starting to remember how I ended up back on windows but with their self admitted whole OS spying shennanigans I'm done with them for good now.
